# searching for special characters sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

i need to search for this character `have a good day" ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) '` that i stored in sqlite database, so i used this sql

```
Select ID From Tasks Where '--' || task || '--' || prio || '--' || due_date ||
'--' ||  [category] || '--' ||  note || '--'  LIKE 
'%have a good day" ! @ [#] [$] \% ^ & * ( ) ''%'  ESCAPE '\'
```

i have used some escaping techniques, but sqlite can't find it, how so i properly escape these special characters when searching an sqlite database

Comment: Sorry, but why would you store something like that?

Comment: an app i developed for a user required it. he stores things lije these. you know users can enter anything in the search

Comment: it looks like you are trying to search for this value in one of the columns you have concatenated. I believe if one of the columns has a NULL value the concatenated result will be NULL as well. So, `ISNULL` is probably your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `LIKE`, not `GLOB`.
The only characters that need escaping are `%` and `_`.

Furthermore, any `NULL` values in the table will make the `LIKE` fail, so you have to convert any possible `NULL`s into something else:

```
Select ID
From Tasks
Where '--' || ifnull(task, '') ||
      '--' || ifnull(prio, '') ||
      '--' || ifnull(due_date, '') ||
      '--' || ifnull(category, '') ||
      '--' || ifnull(note, '') || '--'
      LIKE '%have a good day" ! @ # $ \% ^ & * ( ) ''%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: i modified my query to `Select ID From Tasks Where '--' || task || '--' || prio || '--' || due_date || '--' ||  [category] || '--' ||  note || '--' LIKE '%have a good day ! @ # $ \% ^ & * ( ) ''%'  ESCAPE '\' without result
`

Comment: And you forgot `"` in that string.